# C# Ado.net Entity Framework error?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I create a project to display a list of student on Database (the current.net framework version is 4.6.1). The wizard ask me to add database to the project and I accept it. 
[image]

When I build the project on Debug mode, everything works fine on Windows 10. 
[image]

I copy the debug folder to windows 7 and try to run the project, it shows me the error message.
[image]

```
System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
```

I try to install the .net framework 4.6.1 for windows 7 but it didn't work. This is the list of installed programs on windows 7:
[image]

The list of installed programs on windows 10:
[image]

[image]

I really don't know why my project didn't work on windows 7, are there some missing files or frameworks?

Thanks for your reading :D

Comment: There's no localdb in SQL 2008.

Comment: I think the project can run alone without SQL server. It just depends on .net framework?

Comment: Windows 7 seems not working with SQL Local Database 2014. I installed SQL 2012 Express Local Database and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express targeted to developers."
You can use LocalDB on your development machine, but don't expect it to be working on other machine. I can't tell you an exact solution as it depends on what you are allowed to do. Moving to a "real" database maybe.

Comment: I tried to use the original database by modifying the connection string in App.config (point to C:\TestDatabase.mdf). Then I copy all of them to same location in windows 7, but it still show the error.

Comment: I think, this is because LocalDB (SQL Express) isn't installed on the Win 7 machine. Could you please post the original and the modified connection string?

Comment: This is the created connection string when I attached database to my project: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DemoDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\DemoDatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: That means the SQL Express is required on windows 7?

Comment: Sure. It contains LocalDB.
Also would worth figuring out where |DataDirectory| points, but a simple google search did not yield and usable results for me and i'm on a run.